# Car shakes while stopped with my brake pressed

Tags: brakes, hyundai, elantra, shaking

I just got this Elantra 2012. I notice that when I'm at a red light waiting to move, my foot is on the brake pedal, the car is shaking. It's not a hard shake, but just at my feet and in my seat I can feel it. What might this can be.

Comment: How many miles on your Elantra?

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be the motor mounts. They isolate the vibration of engine from the frame.

Answer (score 1):

That just recently happened to my 2014 Chevy Sonic, turned out that it was a faulty O2 sensor that was making the computer add to much gas into the engine. I'd suggest getting it checked soon, I waited too long and had to rebuild my engine.